# how wrap div around two element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some pair of element,
they are

```
 <h3></h3><ul></ul>
 <h3></h3><ul></ul>
 <h3></h3><ul></ul>
```

I want to wrap a element (div) with jquery around all of this pair

result should be

```
<div> <h3></h3><ul></ul> </div>
<div> <h3></h3><ul></ul> </div>
<div> <h3></h3><ul></ul> </div>
```

How can I achieve it with `jquery.wrap()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate through `h3` elements and using jquery [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select and the `ul` element with [.andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andself/) to include and `h3` element and finally [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) around a `div`:

```js
$('h3').each(function() {
  $(this).next('ul').andSelf().wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
h3 {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
ul {
  border: solid 1px yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>h3</h3>
<ul>ul</ul>
<h3>h3</h3>
<ul>ul</ul>
<h3>h3</h3>
<ul>ul</ul>
```